# Prevent object creation when hardware resource is exhausted

Tags: c++, c++17, embedded

When working on embedded projects you often write a driver for a hardware resource such as a UART (or serial port).
A microcontroller could have multiple different hardware UART instances (sometimes specialisations as well, such as USARTS).

I'm looking for a pattern to allow for creating multiple instances of a driver so that you can use the different hardware peripherals, while guaranteeing that there will only ever be one object that is "attached" or "representing" the physical device.

Having UART1 UART2 UART3 and USART4 and USART5 for example, is there a way to allow this:

```cpp
auto uart1 = UartDriver(UART1, ...);
auto uart2 = UartDriver(UART2, ...);
auto usart4= UsartDriver(USART4, ...);
// later in the code
auto another_instance = UartDriver(UART1, ...); // should not compile
```

I can't use exceptions due to limited resources.

Comment: You can make `UartDriver` into a non-type class template (with e.g. `int` representing the UART number), with a `static_assert` on the template argument value.

Comment: @wohlstad thanks for the suggestion, I've thought about that but this solution doesn't prevent multiple instances of the Driver unless I combine it with a singleton-esque pattern

Comment: What is `UartDriver`? A macro? Function? Type?

Comment: @bitmask a type, it would be a class (maybe to be placement-new'd onto memory-mapped IO) that encapsulates the functionality of the hardware

Comment: After some consideration, I believe having local variables that cannot be instantiated with the same constants and fail to compile otherwise is impossible without singleton-lookup-structures. The reason for this is that an instantiation could happen in a different scope.

Comment: Object creation is a run-time issue so "`// should not compile`" may be rather difficult to achieve - the resource is not "used" until run-time.  Perhaps not impossible, but likely not worth the effort.  Other than that, maintaining a static registry of resource usage is trivial, and the constructor could take some error handling action (such as an `assert` or throw an exception if you allow C++ exceptions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preventing compilation of code that instantiates objects at run-time is likely not possible unless all objects are statically instantiated, and even then I doubt the practicality of any solution.

Run-time checking of resource usage is straightforward however.  For example, in outline:

```
class UsartDriver
{
    public :
        UsartDriver( int usart ) : m_usart(usart)
        {
            assert( !m_resource_in_use[m_usart] ) ;
            m_resource_in_use[m_usart] = true ;
            ...
        }

        ~UsartDriver()
        {
            m_resource_in_use[m_usart] = false ;
        }

        ...

    private :
        static bool m_resource_in_use[MAX_USART] ;
        int m_usart ;    
} ;

bool UsartDriver::m_resource_in_use[MAX_USART] ;
```

Comment: Maybe `std::bitset` is a better choice than a bool-array for a resource-constrained platform.

Comment: @bitmask : perhaps. It was the general principle I was outlining, not a specific implementation. I would not be too concerned where resource count is low.  Also use of templates might not increase code size disproportionately, which may be the resource constraint.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm hesitant to suggest this as a solution to your problem, there is a way to build a tuple of values such that all devices are of different types, with compile-time checks. This makes uses of C++ 11 features:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>
```

First I define a recursive variadic template that checks that the first type in the parameter pack is different from all other types, using `std::is_same`:

```
// base case: true
template<typename... Types>
struct head_distinct {
    static const bool v = true;
};

// general case, T != O and the property holds recursively 
// for T and the remaining types
template<typename T , typename O, typename... Others>
struct head_distinct<T, O, Others...> {
    static const bool v =
       !std::is_same<T, O>::value
    && head_distinct<T, Others...>::v;
};
```

Once you have this, you can have an `alldiffs` predicate trait, that makes sure that all pairs of types are different (the algorithm is quadratic, but at compile-time):

```
// base case: true
template<typename... Types>
struct alldiffs {
    static const bool v = true;
};

// general case: T is distinct from all other Types
// and recursively, alldiffs(Types)
template<typename T, typename... Types>
struct alldiffs<T, Types...> {
    static const bool v = head_distinct<T, Types...>::v 
        && alldiffs<Types...>::v;
};
```

Finally, you can implement a data structure that is basically a tuple, but with a `static_assert` that all types are differents:

```
template<typename ... T>
struct Blob {
    Blob(T&&... args) : tuple(std::forward(...args)) {
        static_assert(alldiffs<T...>::v, 
        "all types must be different");
    };
    std::tuple<T...> tuple;
};
```

For example:

```
class A{};
struct B{};

int main()
{
    Blob<A,B> ok({},{}); // compiles
    Blob<A,A> ko({},{}); // does not compile
}
```

```
<source>: In constructor 'Blob<T>::Blob(T&& ...)':
<source>:29:44: error: expected primary-expression before '...' token
   29 |     Blob(T&&... args) : tuple(std::forward(...args)) {
      |                                            ^~~
<source>: In instantiation of 'Blob<T>::Blob(T&& ...) [with T = {A, A}]':
<source>:42:23:   required from here
<source>:30:39: error: static assertion failed: all types must be different
   30 |         static_assert(alldiffs<T...>::v,
      |                                       ^
<source>:30:39: note: 'alldiffs<A, A>::v' evaluates to false
Compiler returned: 1
```

Comment: This is cool, but my understanding was that different devices are initialised at different points during the runtime of the program. Not all at once. I might be wrong.

Comment: @bitmask I agree, checking that dynamically is better, my guess was that if they want to have a way to check that during compilation then maybe there is a way to organize the code a bit differently so that eventually all the available drivers are stored together at some point, I don't know.

Comment: This is a really cool solution! If it is possible to add the constraint that the drivers must be assigned at compile time this definitely works, but as @bitmask said, it's better to allow runtime initialization and potential destruction.